# Simple proof involving quantifiers

Tags: proof-verification, quantifiers

**Task: Prove this theorem**: $ \exists x (P(x) \Rightarrow \forall yP(y) )$.

**I got this far:** I figured out this is equivalent to $\exists x (\neg P(x) \lor \forall yP(y) )$.

I don't understand however how I can go about completing the proof without any other extra information. I can't really assume anything about the statement $P$ can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assume anything about $P$, nor do you have to.
Note that because $x$ is not free in $\forall y P(y)$, 
$$
\exists x(\neg P(x)\lor \forall y P(y)) \equiv (\exists x \neg P(x)\lor \forall y P(y)). \tag{1}
$$
Now recall that $\exists\neg \equiv \neg\forall$, so the righthand side of (1) is equivalent to
$$
\text{(1)}_{RHS} \equiv (\neg \forall x P(x)\lor \forall y P(y)).\tag{2}
$$
By changing variables, 
$$
\text{(2)}_{RHS} \equiv (\neg \forall y P(y)\lor \forall y P(y)),\tag{3}
$$
which is a tautology, hence provable and valid.
These are all equivalent to the lefthand side of (1), which, as you noticed, is equivalent to the formula you wish to prove.

Comment: I should have been clearer in the question I apologize for that. The goal is not proving that  $ \exists x (P(x) \Rightarrow \forall yP(y) )$ is equivalent to $\exists x (\neg P(x) \lor \forall yP(y) )$ (what I assume you thought was the goal). I have edited the question to more clearly reflect that.

Comment: You're right, I did assume you were asking that different question. I emended my answer to address your actual question.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. So at point $(2)$ it is perfectly all right to change the variable in the statement $\neg \forall xP(x)$ because it is "independent"? (There is probably a formal term for what is going on that I don't know.)

Comment: That's right. "Independent" isn't quite a standard term but you'll be understood. There's no other variable in the scope of the $\forall x$ quantifier, either bound or free, so you can change it to any variable, even $y$. ¶ You're welcome:) & thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$A\implies B$ which is logically equivalent to $\neg A \vee B$. Therefore
$$
\exists x(A\implies B)
$$
is logically equivalent to 
$$
\exists x(\neg A \vee B)
$$
no matter what the statements $A$ and $B$ are.

Comment: I'm sorry but I probably was not clear enough about the goal of the proof. I have edited the question to remedy this.

Answer (score 1):

Using a tableau expansion:

1. Start with: $ \neg (∃x(P(x)⇒∀yP(y)))$
2. The leading connective is $\neg$ then $∃$: $∀x \neg (P(x)⇒∀yP(y))$
3. Instantiate: $ \neg (P(a)⇒∀yP(y))$
4. The leading connective is $\neg$ then $⇒$: $  (P(a)\wedge \neg ∀yP(y))$
5. We now have three formulas:  $∀x \neg (P(x)⇒∀yP(y))$, $  P(a)$ and  $\neg ∀yP(y)$
6. Or: $∀x \neg (P(x)⇒∀yP(y))$, $  P(a)$ and  $∃y \neg P(y)$
7. Introduce a witness term: $\neg P(b)$
8. Instantiate:$ \neg (P(b)⇒∀yP(y))$
9. Or: $  (P(b)\wedge \neg ∀yP(y))$
10. P(b) and $\neg P(b)$
11. Close the branch, hence the tableau.

This theorem is by the way the drinker's theorem. See Drinker paradox -Wikipedia

Comment: Thanks for writing that out. I have actually never seen this method of doing proofs.