# Proving the following deduction

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I am trying to prove $$\vdash \exists x (Px \to \forall x Px)$$ with a formal deduction, but I am stumped. Does anyone see what to do?

Comment: (It's false in an empty model; true in nonempty ones.) Do you understand how to prove it informally?

Comment: You will need to disclose _which formal system_ you want to work in. There are many possible choices, and we can't just take a guess at which one you're using.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412387/why-is-this-true-exists-xpx-rightarrow-forall-y-py (and questions linked from there) -- it is not primarily about _formal_ proofs, but some of the answers do provide them in various systems.

Comment: This is a question from my textbook, so I'm not sure how it could be false. The question just asks to show the above is true, though it falls in the section dealing with first-order predicate logic. Informally, we know that $A\to B$ is false only when $A$ is true, and $B$ is false, so we would want that to be the case for the above to be false.

Comment: You can see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686320/simple-proof-involving-quantifiers) and many many similar post under [drinker's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox).

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know this was a well known question.

Comment: @HughMungus What specific proof system do you work with?  There are many variants!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a formal proof ... but remember that the system you have to use may have its inference rules defined differently!

[image]